# Why am I getting an empty list?

Tags: python-3.x, empty-list

So I am trying to take 2 lists of numbers; slice the first list, reverse the ordering of the sliced list, and then add it to the 2nd list and print the new list. When I run and put all my inputs in I just get an empty list. Can you guys help me find out where I went wrong?

```
 def transform(list1,list2,r1,r2):
        rev_list=[]
        list1=''
        list2=''
        l1=list1.split(',')
        l2=list2.split(',')
        slice_l1=l1[r1:r2]
        for i in reversed(slice_l1):
            rev_list.extend(i)
        new_list=l2+rev_list
        return new_list

    def main():
        user_input_l1=input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by a   comma (,): ")
        user_input_l2=input("Please enter a second list of numbers separated by a comma (,): ")
        user_input_r1=int(input("Please enter the beginning index for slice: "))
        user_input_r2=int(input("Please enter the ending index for slice: "))
        new_list=transform(user_input_l1,user_input_l2,user_input_r1,user_input_r2)
        print("Your new list is",new_list)
        print(type(new_list))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You didn't show your inputs. Try to find a shortest input and add its output. Also please indent the last code chunk.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

`list1 = ''` and `list2 = ''` turn your inputs into the empty string `''`. I believe that wasn't your intention, so it can be deleted?

Then, when you input your numbers, they are in the form of a tuple, which does not have the `.split()` method. I've made a change to those lines to get `l1` and `l2` into list form.

Also, use `.append()` instead of `.extend()` if you are only adding a single number to your list. Alternatively, if you want to use `.extend()`, you would give it a whole list as an argument.

Try this:

```
def transform(list1,list2,r1,r2):
    rev_list=[]
    l1= [item for item in list1]
    l2= [item for item in list2]
    slice_l1=l1[r1:r2]
    rev_list.extend(reversed(slice_l1))
    new_list=l2+rev_list
    return new_list
```

Comment: Thank you snookieordie for your help. Your solution didn't work for me but it did give me the ideas I needed to finally solve my issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to achieve my goal:

```
def transform(list1,list2,r1,r2): 
    rev_list=[] 
    l1=list(list1) 
    l2=list(list2) 
    slice_l1=l1[r1:r2] 
    rev_list.extend(reversed(slice_l1))
    l2.extend(rev_list) # Extends l2 by rev_list
    return l2
```

I used the eval() method on my user input which converted the string from the user's input into a tuple and then I used the list() method on that tuple to convert it into a list.

Thanks again to snookieordie for help.